# Почему данный код JQuery не работает?

Tags: jquery

Только начал учить  JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vel').change(function(){
        if ($('#vel').val())<10 { 
            alert( введите число от 10 до 60)
        }
        if ($('#vel').val())>60 { 
            alert( введите число от 10 до 60)
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что код не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметром функции `alert` является строка.

Литералы строк в javascript должны обрамляться в одиночные или двойные кавычки:

```
alert( 'введите число от 10 до 60' )
...
alert( "введите число от 10 до 60" )
```

---

Условия для оператора `if` должны находиться в круглых скобках:

```
if (($('#vel').val())<10) { 
...
if ($('#vel').val()>60) {
```

---

При вызове функции необходимо закрывать круглые скобки:

```
$('#vel').change(function(){ ... })
```